Displaying MessageID via Powershell
Please, tell me if there is an opportunity to run searching and displaying an MessageID of every single email, which I will get via my code.
I was trying to figure out it, but I have only blank column without any messageid record.
My code is located in attachment.
Many thanks for your answers.
Jochonon
    Invoke-Expression $command | Select-Object Timestamp, EventID, Source, Sender, Recipients,
    MessageSubject, ClientIp, ClientHostname, ServerIp, ServerHostname, RecipientStatus,
    RelatedRecipientAddress, RecipientCount, TotalBytes, MessageInfo, ConnectorID, MesasgeId |
    Out-GridView
    Write-Debug "Hledání bylo dokončeno."



What is $command?

$command = "get-messagetrackinglog    #*for more details, i would like to write u an email

Are you sure that MessageId is provided? What if you do Invoke-Expression $command | Get-Member? Is MessageId part of the properties listed?

No, it isn't. It displays nothing or this:

Import-PSSession : No command proxies have been created, because all of the requested remote commands would shadow existing local commands.  Use the AllowClobber parameter if you want to shadow existing local commands.
At C:\Users\admin02\Desktop\MessageTrackingGUI.ps1:237 char:9


    Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking | Out-Null



    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Import-PSSession], ArgumentException
FullyQualifiedErrorId



